# AWS direct connect with Cisco ASA redendency

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-asa, failover, aws

We have following scenario currently and `BLUE` link is active and running, now i am going to get second link for redendency which is right side of diagram.

[image]

As you can see currently i have VLAN 9 (AWS direct connect) configured and working which i terminated on Cisco ASA firewall and running BGP on it, now i want to setup second backup link to AWS in that case should i need to create new `VLAN 10` `(interface Port-Channel1.10)` to terminated on Cisco ASA? or is there any other method to handle this solution?

Need some advice or guidance how i should handle this kind of scenario and how should i configure BGP to handle failover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating another VLAN is a reasonable way to go.  Yes, you should use BGP to detect when one side becomes unreachable.